# android crash on set event for button from dialog

Tags: android, dialog, crash

I have this code in an android application,it shows an dialog when press on a menu item,it worked fine but when i set functionality for button "send", from dialog box, it crash when menu item is clicked. I can't find the problem

```
 private void showdialog (String ap){
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
    et =(EditText)dialog.findViewById (R.id.commentET);
    send=(Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.send);
    send.setOnClickListener(sendOnClickListener);
    dialog.setTitle(ap);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.comment);
    System.getProperty("line.separator");
    dialog.setCancelable(true);
    dialog.show();
}

Button.OnClickListener sendOnClickListener
= new Button.OnClickListener(){



public void onClick(View arg0) {
  s=et.getText().toString();
  dialog.dismiss();
} 
};




public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
   getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.aprobare_menu, menu);
   return true;
}

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) 
   {


      switch (item.getItemId())
      {
         case R.id.aproba:
             showdialog("Aprobat");
             return true;

         case R.id.respinge:
            showdialog("Respins");
             return true;

       default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
      }
      }    

};
```

Comment: Can you paste the error please?

Comment: show crash log. crystal glass is broken

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the order where you call setContentView:

```
private void showdialog (String ap){
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.comment);
et =(EditText)dialog.findViewById (R.id.commentET);
send=(Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.send);
send.setOnClickListener(sendOnClickListener);
dialog.setTitle(ap);
System.getProperty("line.separator");
dialog.setCancelable(true);
dialog.show();
}
```

Not sure though.

Answer (score 1):

set the `contentView` for your dialog **before** finding any views by id :

```
private void showdialog (String ap){
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.comment);// should be before findViewById
    et =(EditText)dialog.findViewById (R.id.commentET);
    send=(Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.send);
    send.setOnClickListener(sendOnClickListener);
    dialog.setTitle(ap);

    System.getProperty("line.separator");
    dialog.setCancelable(true);
    dialog.show();
}
```

Comment: glad i could help, accept the answer so others can get help from it :)